# Tracking different groups of 'logged in' users

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having a bit of a problem tracking groups of users.

On our site we have two different kinds of "logged-in" users.

We have 'sellers' and 'buyers'.

Is there a way to track these two different types of "logged-in" users separately?
I've managed to track logged-in users vs not logged-in users but I cant find a way to track different types of logged-in users.

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Custom Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) and [Segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en).

For example, for Sellers:

```js
ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Buyer');
```

And for Buyers:

```js
ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Seller');
```

Thus, in pseudo-code, you will probably have something similar to:

```js
if (userIsLoggedIn) { // Assuming a variable to check the user's login status
   ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Logged in');

   if (userGroup === 'Buyer') { // Assuming a variable containing the user's Group
      ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Buyer');
   } else if (userGroup === 'Seller') {
      ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Seller');
   }
} else {
   ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Not logged in');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Im new to GA and still in the learning process.
Would those simple code insertions be able to tag each logged-in user  and track them? Our would I need other code implementations  to match the "Sellers" and "Buyers" in the GA dimensions?

Afterwards I would track them separately through Segments... right?

Comment: Updated my answer with pseudo-code regarding setting Dimensions according to some business logic. Ultimately, you will need to check whether the user is a Buyer or a Seller, based on your application data or based on data available on the page. Then you would create Segments in Analytics based on the Custom Dimensions you created (one for "Buyers" and another for "Sellers"). For a fairly complete introduction to Segments, you might be interested in reading http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/07/16/google-analytics-segmentation/

Comment: Question: when you are creating the custom dimension on GA, do you add it as Session or User?